# Laravel 4 large Route count increases booting time

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing

We have a large web application built on Laravel 4 (4.2 currently) and we have ran into a bit of a problem. Each page load takes about 900ms just to boot up the Laravel. We did some investigation and looks that it is caused by large route count in our application - we have a list of around 1200 - 1500 routes when I launch `php artisan routes` So my guess is the long load time is due the fact, that In booting process Laravel will go over all of those routes and map them... I also trieed just removing all of them and have one test route, and then the app boots up normally - in about 100 - 150ms as it should...

We have the routes spread out between many controllers in several workbench packages and also in /app/routes.php. We are using RESTful and normal controllers.

Has anyone had such a problem with a large scale application with many routes? How to solve it and not have Laravel go through all of them and map them at the booting process?

Comment: I think you should get interested in routes caching. For example https://packagist.org/packages/ipunkt/laravel-route-cache (I haven't used it). In Laravel 5 there will be routes caching built in so it should work better

Comment: Ya, We trieed that approach, but what it does is cache the route responses rather than the map it self. And we dont have any problems with the responses, and it will still hav eto go through all of the routes on page load, with is the slow bit...

Comment: This isn't worth of an full answer but -- 1800 individual routes seems like a lot.  My first approach here would be a re-factoring of the routes to look for common patterns and have a single smart route declaration replace as many of the individual routes as possible.

Comment: Thought about it as well and we might be able to get to like 1/3 of them down, but still it wont fix the issue completely... In our application we have tons of small ajax requests and stuff, that takes up individual controller method and we cant combine a lot of them together...

Answer (score 3):

Although it's harder to maintain, you could try to separate your routes based on the first segment:

```
$first = Request::segment(1);

if ($first === 'blog') {
    // add blog routes here
} elseif ($first === 'forum') {
    // add forum routes here
}
```

But it will make the other routes unavailable to helpers like URL::route('resource.action').

You also need to know if there's any slow code in your routes.php, like:

```
Route::resource('page', slowFunctionToDecideControllerName());
```

UPDATE: Laravel 5 has a route cache system https://mattstauffer.co/blog/laravel-5.0-route-caching